# Unity3D Android - Move your character to a specific x position

Tags: unity, android

I want to move my character (which is a cube for now) to a specific x location (on top of a flying floor/ground thingy) but I've been having some troubles with it. I've been using this script:

```
var jumpSpeed: float = 3.5;
var distToGround: float;

function Start(){
    // get the distance to ground
    distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
}

function IsGrounded(): boolean {
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1);
}

function Update () {
    // Move the object to the right relative to the camera 1 unit/second.
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.anyKeyDown && IsGrounded()){
        rigidbody.velocity.x = jumpSpeed;
    }
}
```

And this is the result (which is not what I want):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj8B6eI4dbE

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I'm using UnityScript (Javascript).

Comment: You're increasing the x velocity. Seems like it's working exactly like you coded it. Are you just wanting to move it to the next track?

Comment: Exactly,that's what im trying to do.

Comment: Then don't modify the velocity. Modify the position.

Comment: Something like this ? :    transform.position = transform.position + (new Vector3(0, 0));

Comment: Yes, except provide three coordinates for the Vector3. If you want to move over time, you'll need to use Lerp. Update your question with the specifics of what you want, not just telling us that i's not working.

Comment: Can you actualy help me out with that,I've been trying to figure out what you said all day long but didn't achieve anything.